# Unexpected server response (204) while retrieving PDF

Tags: yii2, yii

Подключил расширение `yii2assets\pdfjs`, но когда я вызываю его получаю такую ошибку 
`PDF.js v1.4.20 (сборка: b15f335)
Сообщение: Unexpected server response (204) while retrieving PDF "http://univer.lc/upload/page/page1/7.pdf".`

Вот код вызова виджета в представлении

```
<?= \yii2assets\pdfjs\PdfJs::widget([
   'url'=> Url::base().'/upload/page/page1/7.pdf',
]); ?>
```

Ответ:
Нашел решение, нужно в строке поиск браузера изменить http на https, так как при http заголовке начинается загрузка файла через IDM